# How to test two entries per line to given intervals?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a reference file **ref** with certain values (v1 and v2), and for every value there is an interval with upper (ub) and lower (lb bonds) and a group number (gn)defined:

```
v1 v2 ub1   lb1   ub2 lb2 gn
50 25 51    49    26  24  1
86 13 86.5  85.5  14  12  2
...
```

Now I have a file **test** with many lines and two of the entries of every line have values that lie within the intervals defined in **ref**. The goal is to assign every line the group number which corresponds to the entries in the reference file.

Input file:

```
50.2 24.6
85.7 13.9
86.3 12.6
```

Desired output:

```
50.2 24.6 1
85.7 13.9 2
86.3 12.6 2
```

My approach so far is this code with **bash** and **awk**:

```
while read line
do

lin=( ${line} )
rot=${lin[0]}
tilt=${lin[1]}

awk  -v line="${line}" -v rot="$rot"  -v tilt="$tilt" ' {if ((rot>$4) && (rot<$3) && (tilt>$6) && (tilt<$5)) {print line,$7} } ' reference >> output

done < test
```

But it won't work, the **test** file has 130000 lines, but the output file has only 11000. So obviously I am doing something wrong. I'm grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: using read on big file is not efficient because it is slow, awk can already loop over lines, reference file should be loaded in a memory structure like a map then test file could be processed

Comment: The script with the code finishes normally, so efficiency is not the problem I guess.

Comment: the reason why it has fewer lines is the `if`, when condition is false `print` is not done, ah also the decimal separator is `.` not `,`

Comment: also `0+$4` may be used to explicitly convert to a number otherwise awk may do a lexicographic comparison

Comment: I will try this on Monday, thank you for your input. As I am not fluent in awk, how would you do this only using it?

Answer (score 0):

with the `.` used as decimal separator

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR && NR>1{ub1[$NF]=$3;lb1[$NF]=$4;ub2[$NF]=$5;lb2[$NF]=$6; next} 
                      {for(k in lb1) 
                         if(lb1[k]<$1 && $1<ub1[k] && 
                            lb2[k]<$2 && $2<ub2[k]) print $0, k}' file input
50.2 24.6 1
85.7 13.9 2
86.3 12.6 2
```

you may need to change the locale settings to use `,` as the decimal separator.  Also the code assumes there is one pair of ranges per group number (so indexed ranges with group number), if not you need to index by row number and keep a mapping to row number to group number as well.

Comment: The decimal separator is indeed the dot, sorry for the confusion, my localized keyboard writes a comma for it when using the separator on the NumPad. My bad ;)

And indeed every group number contains a range of two values. In fact, they are orientation groups and the values are pairs of angles. Every group number is associated with two intervals in which the two angles should be. And every pair of angles in the test file should be assigned to one (orientation) group which are definied in the reference file.